# Math notation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

How can I write e^(3j) in LaTeX?

I have tried many syntax, like `$e^(3j)$` or `$e^*{3j}$`

Any help will be very well received.

Comment: What about `$e^{3j}$` or `$e^{(3j)}$` depending on what you want.

Comment: (at least) 3 people think this is well researched, it's also some how become a "hot question" - this is a prime example of what's wrong with the hot questions, people who know absolutely nothing come along and are like "Yeah, that's a good question" (3 upvotes is rather small, I've seen some 'if you knew what the [se site name] was about you wouldn't upvote this' hit as high as 65 upvotes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I produce exponents with variables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338373/how-do-i-produce-exponents-with-variables)

Comment: I've closed the linked question as a duplicate of this one, since this one is much older.

Answer (score 10):

Group the exponent in curly braces, and use the ^ sign to make it a superscript. If you really need parentheses, add them inside the braces too.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$e^{3j}$ or $e^{(3j)}$%a variable e
\quad
$\mathrm{e}^{3j}$% e as a constant
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I feel one should use `\exp` and define it to one's likings, but that's debatable

Comment: @Bort But there are times when one wants to write $\exp(blah)$ and times when one wants to write $\mathrm{e}^{blah}$. The former is well-suited to complicated expressions; the latter to simple ones.