# How to write a power set such as 2^{a}. only the first bracket gets raised to the 2

Tags: typography

[image]

[image]

I just need this format for writing power sets properly but its not formating correctly

Comment: `$2^{\{a\}}$`, perhaps, assuming you really want visible braces.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It's really helpful if you provide a minimal working example that shows what you have so far.  `2^{a}` would not yield braces.  One way that would give the output you showed is `2^\{a\}`, which is fixed the way that @ StevenB.Segletes suggests.

Comment: There is also \lbrace and \rbrace, more typing but easier to read.

Comment: Duplicate: [Math notation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261616)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you were trying to do.

The usual advice for TeX is to write base^{exponent}, putting braces around the exponent.  Everyone fairly quickly discovers that you can leave off the braces if the exponent is a single token (they also discover other times you can leave off the braces that I won't talk about).  And as soon as someone needs to type `{`, they find out they should precede it with a backslash.

This leads us to what you probably tried: `$2^\{a\}$`.  The problem is that the `^` is followed by three tokens: `{`, `a`, and `}`.  This means that the `^` only exponentiates the first token that it finds, leading to your output.  But if you want to exponentiate more than one token, you need to enclose them in `{` and `}`.  Otherwise, you would be expecting TeX to discover when the exponentiation should end.  This leads you to the commented suggestion: `$2^{\{a\}}$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 $ 2^a \quad 2^{a} \quad 2^\{a\} \quad 2^{\{a\}} $
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]