# trouble with writing negative fractional exponential

Tags: math-mode, equations

Code:

```
\begin{equation*}
    v_o = (v_i - V_D) e^-\frac{ t}{\tau}
\end{equation*}
```

What I want:

[image]

What I am getting:

[image]

Comment: The exponent will be the 1 character after `^` unless you specify otherwise. Try changing your code to `e^{-\frac{ t}{\tau}}` to show you want everything inside `{}` to be the exponent. As you wrote it LaTeX interprets as `e^{-}\frac{ t}{\tau}`.

Comment: More useful information: [Math notation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261616)

Comment: I would use `$\exp(-t/\tau)$` for legibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three main choices for typesetting the exponential expression that has the number `e` as its base: (a) use a `\frac` term in the exponent (and don't forget to enclose the exponent in curly braces); (b) use an inline-fraction term in the exponent; and (c) use `\exp(...)` notation to avoid creating an exponent in the first place.

[image]

All three choices are "correct" from a purely mathematical point of view. However, do note that the `t` and `\tau` terms are typeset in `\scriptscriptstyle`, `\scripstyle`, and `\textstyle`, respectively, according to the first, second, and third choice. For comparison, the terms `e` and `exp`, respectively, are always typeset in `\textstyle`.

Unless you're really short on horizontal space, do consider using either the second or the third method instead of the first. Your readers will likely appreciate you being considerate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \quad e^{-t/\tau} \quad \exp(-t/\tau)
\]
\end{document}
```